# UserProfileChangeCollection - Get unique account name from the collection

Tags: user-profile-property

i have UserProfileChangeCollection collection with all the changes for the uses made in user profile.
Can i get the unique user [i.e. Account name property of user profile] from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MSDN:

- [How to: Get Recent User Profile Changes Using the Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms517376.aspx)
- [UserProfileChange Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilechange_members.aspx) - [UserProfileChange.AccountName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilechange.accountname.aspx)

This code  should work (I didn't tested it!):

```
UserProfileChangeCollection changes = ...... ; 
foreach (UserProfileChange change in changes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(change.AccountName.ToString());
}
```